# How to push a big NextJS project to GitHub

Tags: git, github, next.js

I want to push my NextJS Project to GitHub but I always get an error that says my .next/cache folder exceeds GitHub's file size limit.

I tried to solve this by adding the next folder to the .gitignore file.

**This is my .gitignore file**

```
node_modules
next
.env
```

Then I followed this steps:

1. Make changes in `.gitignore` file
2. Run `git rm -r --cached .` command.
3. Run `git add .` command
4. `git commit -m "Commit message"` or just `git commit` or continue working.
5. `git push`

But it still didn't work.

**Error that I got**

```
remote: error: File .next/cache/webpack/client-development/32.pack is 122.93 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File .next/cache/webpack/client-development/71.pack is 126.09 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File .next/cache/webpack/client-development/9.pack is 155.84 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Did I write something wrong in my .gitignore file or is there another problem?

Thank's for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is that the files may have been deleted, but they still exist in the history of the repository between when you last pushed and now. A file that's committed and then deleted in a later commit still exists in the repository history.

In order to resolve the issue you'll therefore need to remove them from the repository history entirely. https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/removing-files-from-a-repositorys-history provides some guidance on doing this.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me was this:

```
git rm --cached .next/ -r
```

Then checking git status

```
git status
```

Check how far ahead you are

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 8 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then run the following appending how far ahead you are

```
git reset HEAD~8
```

Then:

```
git add .
git commit -m "bug fix"
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 1):

next and .next are different folders.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like OP's `.gitignore` file should have had `.next` instead of `next`, before they did their `git add .`.