# Why am I seeing these webpack events when I check git status using nextjs?

Tags: git, webpack, next.js

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12FKW.png)

I committed the changes and pushed to origin. Should I not do that?

Answer (score -1):

I removed these logs using `git rm -r --cached .next`

and then included .next in .gitignore file

[How to push a big NextJS project to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782039/how-to-push-a-big-nextjs-project-to-github)

https://gist.github.com/vmarcosp/bd32bdbbd74f0cfaac81df902f733bba

https://dev.to/momentum/what-to-do-if-you-accidentally-committed-your-nodemodules-323o